# c++ pass multiple data types (including arrays of different dimensions) to function

Tags: c++, if-statement, templates, dtype

i am trying to create a class that can handle tensors. In the constructor of the function i want to pass inputs of different data types (int, vectors...). I also want to pass arrays that always have different dimensions (1D, 3D...). For the constructor i figured out something like this:

```
template <class T>
Tensor(T input) {
  // ...      
}
```

However, how should i do to get what dtype has been passed in order to do things with the input?
I'd hope in something like this:

```
if (isInt(input)) {

} else if (isFloat(input)) {

} /* and so on for vectors, strings etc... */ {

} else if (isArray(input)) {
   int dim = getDimension(input);
}
```

This is actually the full class:

```
// Take `Tensor` template parameters, defining its
// content data type. Use `float32` as default.
template <class D = float64>
// Define Tensor class.
class Tensor {
  public:
    // Define class constructor.
    template <class T>
    Tensor(T input) {
      using content_dtype = D;
    }
};
```

Comment: which standard? 20, 17?

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki i am am using c++17

Comment: have you tried overloading constructor? like:

```
Tensor(const float input) { ... }
Tensor(const int input) { ... }
Tensor(const std::string& input) { ... }
```

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki yes, but i had some problems with the handling of the arrays. Also i found out that using templates was the most efficient way in terms of code.

Comment: Do you mean "handle tensors" like a Tensor data type is one of the potential constructor arguments? Or is this class supposed to _be_ your tensor datatype?

Comment: the class is supposed to be a tensor datatype, and that function is its constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [constexpr-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class D = double>
class Tensor {
public:
    using content_dtype = D; // put it here for everyone to see

    template <class T>
    Tensor(const T& input) {
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) {
            if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
                if constexpr (std::is_unsigned_v<T>) {
                    std::cout << "arithmetic::itegral::unsigned\n";
                } else {
                    std::cout << "arithmetic::itegral::signed\n";
                }
            } else {
                std::cout << "arithmetic::floating_point\n";
            }
        } else if constexpr (std::is_array_v<T>) {
            auto dim = std::extent_v<T>;
            std::cout << "array with extent " << dim << '\n';
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    unsigned a;
    int b;
    double c;
    int d[10];

    Tensor A{a};
    Tensor B{b};
    Tensor C{c};
    Tensor D{d};
}
```

Output:

```
arithmetic::itegral::unsigned
arithmetic::itegral::signed
arithmetic::floating_point
array with extent 10
```

Comment: Template-specialization could have been cleaner. Depends on what OP wants, of course.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Yes, it could become many levels of indentation here, but it maps 1:1 to what OP had in mind - if I interpreted the question correctly that is.

Comment: hi ,thanks for your answer, that is really good actually! See my recent edit at my question, is it possible to implement your code to something like that?

Comment: Wow, thanks, what's exactly the difference between itegral and int?

Comment: @Giuppox You're welcome! The `is_integral_v` test evaluates to `true` for _all_ integral types, like `short`, `int`, `long` etc. and their `unsigned` counterparts.

Comment: hi, i don't exactly understand what's the meaning of that `const T&` or of `<T>`

Comment: @Giuppox You used `Tensor(T input)` and I changed that to taking the argument by reference (`&`) instead to be able to catch the extent of arrays. Since I suspect that no changes should be made to the argument (`input`) I made it a `const` reference (`const&`).

Comment: i'm sorry but, how should i actually access the value of the input?

Comment: @Giuppox Just uncomment `/* input */` and then use that variable (which is of type `T`). I just commented it out to not cause warnings about an unused variable. I removed that now.

Comment: Ow. Thanks for your help and time, and sorry for the huge amount of questions :/

Comment: @Giuppox You're welcome and no worries! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without going into much questions about what exactly your class is going to provide and whether using templates here makes sense, what you have in mind can be transformed into working C++17 code using `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
    ...
} else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {
    ...  
}
```

Now for types like `std::vector` you would have to come up with your own traits like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_vector : std::false_type {
};

template <typename... Args>
struct is_vector<std::vector<Args...>> : std::true_type {
};
```